# AKS Load Balancer IP Address Not Accessible

Tags: azure-aks

I created a load balancer for service in AKS, and the load balancer got approved to be accessible from AKS Network Subnet Group. The load balancer has an external IP address corresponding to an internal service. But I'm not able to access the IP address provided by the load balancer.

Answer (score 5):

Please perform a `kubectl get service -n <namespace>` on the AKS cluster:

If you see something like the following, where the External-IP is a Public IP address:

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)        AGE
my-service   LoadBalancer   10.0.192.89   20.69.145.115     80:31541/TCP   6s
```

then the Service was allocated a Public IP address from the Frontend IP addresses of the AKS public Load Balancer. Please ensure that all [Network Security Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview) associated with the AKS cluster subnet or the node virtual machines' network interfaces effectively ***Allow*** *Inbound traffic* from the Internet or the Public IP address (range) from which you are trying to connect. Please also ensure that there are no Firewalls, Network Virtual Appliances etc. which blocks inbound traffic to the AKS cluster subnet and node virtual machines.

If you see something like the following where the External-IP is a private IP address:

```
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
my-service   LoadBalancer     10.0.184.168   10.240.0.25   80:30225/TCP   4m
```

then you have created an [Azure Internal Load Balancer Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb) on the AKS cluster and a private IP address from the associated virtual network was associated to the *Service*. Please ensure that you are connecting to the Service from a device inside the AKS cluster's virtual network or a connected network(like [peered virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering), [virtual networks connected over a VPN gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal), [on-premise network connected to the Azure Virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal?toc=/azure/virtual-network/toc.json)). Default Network Security Group rules allow connectivity inside the virtual network and connected networks, however if custom rules are added please ensure that the effective rules allow traffic between the source and the AKS cluster subnet and node Virtual machines.

In a third scenario, you might see the External-IP `<pending>` for a very long time as in the following:

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
my-service   LoadBalancer   10.0.192.89   <pending>     80:31541/TCP   45m
```

In this case please describe the *Service* using `kubectl describe service`. Under the events section of the output, you might find errors during `EnsuringLoadBalancer`. Please ensure that annotations are correctly set in the service manifest and correct permissions are granted to the AKS cluster's managed identity or service p[rincipal as described in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb and/or 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip

Comment: SO I ran into this issue, just to add some clarity to this answer: The NSG must have a rule that allows traffic to the PUBLIC IP, not the nodes. AKS SHOULD add this automatically to the NSG assigned to the node NICs, but if you have your own NSG at the subnet level, it must have the same rules